# Not able to use JohnSnowLabs pretrained model in Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I want to use the JohnSnowLabs pretrained spell check module in my Zeppelin notebook. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp#pre-compiled-spark-nlp-and-spark-nlp-ocr) I have added `com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp_2.11:1.7.3` to the Zeppelin dependency section as shown below:

[image]

However, when I try to run the following simple code

```
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.DocumentAssembler
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotator.NorvigSweetingModel
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotators.Tokenizer
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.Finisher

val df = Seq("tiolt cde", "eefg efa efb").toDF("names")

val nlpPipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(
  new DocumentAssembler().setInputCol("names").setOutputCol("document"),
  new Tokenizer().setInputCols("document").setOutputCol("tokens"),
  NorvigSweetingModel.pretrained().setInputCols("tokens").setOutputCol("corrected"),
  new Finisher().setInputCols("corrected")
))

df.transform(df => nlpPipeline.fit(df).transform(df)).show(false)
```

it gives an error as follows:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, executor 0): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/root/cache_pretrained/spell_fast_en_1.6.2_2_1534781328404/metadata/part-00000 does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:346)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
...
```

How can I add this JohnSnowLabs spelling check pretrained model in Zeppelin? The above code works when directly ran on the Spark-shell.

Comment: Isn't that configuration problem unrelated to Zeppelin? I'd *guess* that you use cluster, but default file system somehow resolves to a local one.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have problem with auto download of pre-trained models/pipelines due to your environment, you can always load them manually.

Here is an example for loading a French model (same concept for any other annotator):

```
val french_pos = PerceptronModel.load("/tmp/pos_ud_gsd_fr_2.0.2_2.4_1556531457346/")
      .setInputCols("document", "token")
      .setOutputCol("pos")
```

Source:
https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/docs/en/models